# How JDBC implementation works

Tags: java, jdbc

In JDBC, I see that `Connection` is an interface, which defines methods for interacting with Database.

I also know that interface contains only abstract methods, and cannot be instantiated

But In JDBC code, how does the following work,

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("URL String");

Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
```

As per my doubt `createStatement()` should be a abstract method, i..e, without any body

But every thing works fine... with this

Can anyone explain?

Comment: It provides classes which implement the interfaces.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(connection.getClass());`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DriverManager.getConnection` returns an object which implements the `Connection` interface - behind the scenes there is a real object.

Answer (score 8):

JDBC is like any driver mechanism - ahead of time the folks and Sun (now Oracle) defined the interface (or contract) that Java would use to interact with a database.  It was then the responibility of the database vendors to provide implementations of that interface in order for their particular database to be used with Java.

The take away here is that the JDBC API defines the standard interface through which Java will interact with a database, the obvious benefit being that, providing your code only uses the JDBC API, it will be reasonably uniform regardless of the database you use, meaning you can therefore swap one implementation with another (although it's not always that simple in practice).

With regards to how implementations of the JDBC API are registered with the [java.sql.DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html),  what used to happen was that your code would need to explicitly load the class(es) implementing [java.sql.Driver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html); the act of loading the class caused it to be registered with the [java.sql.DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).  This mechanism has now be replaced with the [service provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) but the end result is still the same:

*One or more implementations of [java.sql.Driver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) are registered with the [java.sql.DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).*

If you then look at the source code for [java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)) you will see that it simply loops through the registered drivers until it finds one that accepts the connection url at which point the [java.sql.DriverManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) calls the [java.sql.Driver.connect(String, Properties)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#connect-java.lang.String-java.util.Properties-) method, returning a specific implementation of [java.sql.Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html).

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of defining abstract classes (or interfaces) is to have subclasses of the abstract class (or classes implementing the interface), providing an implementation for all the abstract methods of the abstract class (or of the interface). Otherwise, an abstract class or interface could never be used, and would be completely pointless.

So, what DriverManager.getConnection does, in fact, is the following:

```
return new MySqlConnection();
```

or

```
return new OracleConnection();
```

depending on the URL (this is an oversimplified explanation. In reality, it's a bit more complex than that).

and MySQLConnection and OracleConnection are concrete classes implementing the Connection interface:

```
public class MySQLConnection implements Connection {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what `DriverManager` is doing, if it was it would have to know about every implementation of `Connection`, which it can't.  What actually happens is a combination of the service provider mechanism (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider) being used to register an implementation of `java.sql.Driver` with the `java.sql.DriverManager`

Comment: Hence the note: "this is an oversimplified explanation. In reality, it's a bit more complex than that". The point here is not to explain the service provider mechanism, reflection, and so on. The point is to explain that an inctance of a concrete class implementing Connection is created and returned.

Comment: Thank you So much  @JB Nizet, It was clearly explained

Comment: @JBNizet yes, noticed that after I commented :-)  Though read the question differently, sounds like the OP needs to understand OO a bit better

Answer (score 1):

An interface reference can point to any object of a class that implements this interface
 i.e. see the example below:

```
interface Foo{
void display();
}

public class TestFoo implements Foo{

void display(){
System.out.println(“Hello World”);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
Foo foo = new TestFoo();
foo.display();
}

}
```